# Can't review questions as unsalvageable in the triage review when the flag limit is reached

Tags: feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts, triage

In the triage review, I would like to review questions as unsalvageable, but when I reach the maximum number of flags per day, I can't review them as unsalvageable since I can't flag them. This leaves me with two options: either I skip the question and go to the next question (which is probably the best option), or else I review the post as requires editing. This issue can make people review posts as requires editing when they actually are unsalvageable.

I suggest making it possible either to review questions as unsalvageable in the triage review when the flag limit is reached or exceed the flag limit when reviewing triage questions. I don't know which of these options is best or if there is another way of solving this issue, but I really think that posts should be able to be reviewed as unsalvageable even if the person reviewing them runs out of flags for the day, since this issue can tempt people to review unsalvageable questions as requires editing.